# Yahoo finance api chart

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

The following URL has been used to get chart: https://chart.finance.yahoo.com/t?s=sld&width=250&height=180. Everything was fine. But now I get error: Could not process this "GET" request. What URL should be used now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what has happened to yahoo, I get the same response.

After reading your question I decided to update my routines to read from https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?i=60&p=15d&f=d,o,h,l,c,v&df=cpct&q=$ticker instead.

If you do go down that path make sure to take note of the epoch and intervals as mentioned [here](http://www.networkerror.org/component/content/44.html?task=view)